# Active state not working with CSS Sprite

Tags: css, image, sprite

I need help on making sure Domestic Card Tab remains that way when clicked on. I took that screenshot while it was on hover. I have the class:hover working while it is on hover, but class:active is not working when the tab is being clicked on. I'm new to CSS please. Screenshot/Code below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahj6ljk25cy48b9/Screenshot%202016-10-10%2014.04.53.png?dl=0

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
                          #test {
                           display: block; width: 100%; height: 67px; 
                           background: url(images/domestic-main.png)
                           no-repeat;
                           border-left: 1px solid #747474;
                           border-right: 1px solid #747474;}

                         #test:hover{
                           background-position: -208px 0%;
                           position: relative;
                           border-right: none;
                           border-top: none;
                           border-bottom: none;
                           width: 120%;
                           color: white;}

                        #test.a:hover {
                          color: white;}

                        #test a:active {
                           background-position: -208px 0%;
                           position: relative;
                           border-right: none;
                           border-top: none;
                           border-bottom: none;
                           color: white;}

                        #test:active{
                           background-position: 50px 0%;
                           position: relative;}

                        #test:current{
                           background-position: -100px 0%;
                           position: relative;}

                        </style>
                        <li class="" >
                        <a href="#domestic-card-tab" id="test"><p                  
                        style="width=100%;" id="current">
                       Domestic Card Payment</p></a>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`:active`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) does not magically work for your tabs. It only works for links/anchors and other native elements. You need to add a class, for example `.active` to the active tab when the it's clicked. Here's a very basic example:

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $('.tab').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab">Tab1</div>
<div class="tab">Tab2</div>
<div class="tab">Tab3</div>
```